# How to decode Google translate response with php?

Tags: php, json, google-translate

When you GET or POST this: 
`"http://translate.google.com/translate_a/t","client=t&sl=auto&tl=".urlencode($lang)."&text=".urlencode($text)`

the response looks like this:

`[[["автомобил","car","avtomobil",""]],,"en",,[["автомобил",[5],1,0,1000,0,1,0]],[["car",5,[["автомобил",1000,1,0],["автомобилот",0,1,0],["автомобили",0,1,0],["кола",0,1,0],["возило",0,1,0]],[[0,3]],"car"]],,,[["en","fr"]],30]`

How to decode that? (maybe in json_decode style)

Comment: Did you try json_decode?

Answer (score 9):

To get the api to return JSON  change the parameter

```
client=t
```

to

```
client=p
```

Comment: what's the client parameter mean? and there is a document? Thank you!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, it's undocumented functionality.

Comment: your answer helped me a lot and i have attached the full answer below.thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
 //this will translate from en to ar -- you can change it for your needs
 function translate_word($en){
    $file_content = file_get_contents('http://translate.google.com/translate_a/t?client=p&sl=auto&tl=ar&hl=en&sc=2&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&uptl=ar&oc=1&prev=conf&psl=auto&ptl=en&otf=1&it=sel.8936&ssel=0&tsel=3&q='.str_replace(" ","%20",$en));
    $obj = json_decode($file_content);
    if(!empty($obj->sentences[0]->trans)){
        return $obj->sentences[0]->trans;
    }else{
        return $en;
    }
}
//how to use
echo translate_word("test translation process");
//if you do not know short codes for your language you can just open
```

[translate.google.com](http://translate.google.com) and do described on screenshot

```
//you should have firebug extension installed on your browser
```

[image]

```
//if the answer was usefull please do not forget to vote up! thanks.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using PHP's [`json_decode` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to convert that data to native PHP data types.

Comment: you should use client=p in pars of google url first to enable json_decode fun